# Can't log in after upgrading kernel to 3.16

Tags: 14.04, kernel, login

I was running 14.04 and everything worked great till I installed kernel 3.16 with the command `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic` and rebooted.

Now I am unable to log in. It boots up to my log on screen (only one screen is working now) but when I put my password in it acts as if it is logging in but goes back the the login screen (login loop). I can enter the tty, from which I ran an update. Yet I'm still unable to login via the GUI.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. It looks like video driver did not build for the new kernel. Anyway you can boot into 3.13 using grub menu. Old kernel is still there.

Comment: @Pilot6: if you tell him how to back out of the change, the above comment is an answer IMHO!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby Feel free to write it yourself ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 [Yes, my master!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2QvAqP6mxg8)  **;-)**

Answer (score 1):

It's never a good thing to try and mix kernels from other versions of Ubuntu; it's not even something I would try to do: I would just upgrade to that version... (and getting kernels from another version is not supported here neither).

Therefore, just restore the [system backup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) you took *before* you tried to do this...

Oh?  Right!  You don't have a system back-up!  **:-(** Well, read the above link and start making system back-ups from now on.

To back out of the current mess, reboot Ubuntu into a previous kernel by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> while booting, boot the second-newest kernel you have on your system, install `synaptic`:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and then run it, delete the 3.16 linux image and headers and reboot again.

Comment: No! This will not remove the kernel.  It is meta package. After second reboot it will be the same kernel.

Comment: I suggest to wait for OP's response.

Comment: Better?????????

Comment: I have no idea if grub-customizer can remove kernels. I would use synaptic for that. I suspect grub-customizer only can remove some items from menu. After update-grub it appears again. Never used that customizer.

Comment: I use `grub-customizer´ to edit the menu and `gtk-orphan` to remove orphaned stuff...

Comment: I fixed it. It is not a matter of the menu. Kernel must be removed.

Comment: спасибо! Thanking you with some work now...  ;-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25580/discussion-between-fabby-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your responses, but I end up just purged the 3.16 kernel and rebooted. Kernel is now back at 3.13 and everything is good.

Comment: That is exactly what we suggested.

Comment: @Pilot6, Yes you did suggest that and that is why i'm thanking all of you, because you did help. The "just purged" comment was just to infer that I couldn't fix it with out going back to my old kernel.